# pause signal in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I want a `pause` or `pauseUntil` signal in ReactiveCocoa that behaves similarly to `skipUntil` except instead of just skipping values sent on `self` until `skipUntil` receives a trigger signal, I want `pause`/`pauseUntil` to conditionally wait AND collect values and when the trigger signal fires, forward all values that have been collected.

The `pauseUntil` function would take a trigger signal (`Signal<(), NoError>`) and once it fires, `self` would behave like normal.

The `pause` function on the other hand would act as a toggle, taking an argument of `Signal<Bool, NoError>`, effectively pausing and un-pausing the signal in question.